# StackMaps - Interactive Maps of StackExchange Communities

Tags: discussion

[image: StackMaps Logo]

## [StackMaps](http://johndbritton.com/stackmaps) - Interactive Maps of StackExchange Communities

http://johndbritton.com/stackmaps

### What

Easily view users from your favorite StackExchange community on a map.

### Why

I wanted to make it easy to browse the [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com) users by location, so I built this little hack as part of my [48HourApps](http://48hourapps.com) series. It works for all StackExchange sites.

### Who

Created by [John Britton](http://johndbritton.com)

Logo built to order by [Chris Kennedy](http://kennedysgarage.com). Marker "[spiderfying](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier)" by [George MacKerron](http://mackerron.com/home/). Searchable dropdown using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen) by [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/). Google Maps, jQuery, and GitHub were used too.

Comment: Hope the members of Travel.SE find the app useful.

Comment: ull get a lot of praise id u post this under gis meta

Comment: This is very, very cool. Can you let me know what dataset you're working with here and how it's tabulated? (Can't find myself on a couple sites.) Thx!

Comment: @SamTheBrand I'm using the Stack Exchange API. It only loads the top 500 users by reputation at first, but you can click "show more users" and it should show you. If you still can't find yourself, make sure you have your location set in your profile and that it can be geocoded.

Comment: @johndbritton you might want to indicate this once the first 500 users are loaded as I would have definitely missed that if I did not read your comment here ;) Congrats btw, very cool app

Answer (score 3):

Only showing the top X users, or users with a certain amount of reputation would be useful. When looking at who's who on JL&U, someone like [this user](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/303/andro-selva) who has never interacted on that Stack Exchange is more "noise" than "signal".

Comment: By default it only shows the top 500 users by reputation, clicking "show more users" displays 500 more on each click. Limiting to users with more than 100 rep might also help.

Answer (score 2):

This is really nice, thanks!

Not familiar with the interface though.. when the location is only a country I understand that it's using some default map location but what determines that default location? Surely not the capital of the country, considering this case:

[image: screenshot]

Maximum zoom level showed it's located in some abandoned field.

Comment: The geocoding API that I'm using controls where to place the markers. If only a country name is included it might use the geometric center or something. I'm not using the default Google geocoder because the rate limit is too low. Instead, I'm using one provided by Yahoo. It would be nice if SE included LatLng in the API responses.