# Map addition to user profile

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

I know there is the [StackMaps](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733/1381) app, showing where users are based, which gives a good idea of the general location of the community, but I thought what might be interesting for Travel is an addition to the profile to display all the countries a user has been to (maybe selected from a box during profile edit)

Currently [traveltip.org](http://www.traveltip.org/countries_visited.php) does this. I quickly did one in traveltip and inserted it into my profile so it looks like this, but it would be nice to have it as a native application:

[image]

Comment: If you have an account in traveltip.com, you can show an interactive map, so once you update the countries you visited the linked map will be updated.. use this as the image source: www.traveltip.org/pix/user_countries.php?user=YOUR_USER_ID_HERE&s=md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not worth the bother. Too few users are even inclined to show anything meaningful under Location in their Profile. Out of over 33k users only 55 have provided details [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3908/4995).

Comment: To be fair, as I do the majority of my SE stuff on a mobile app, I hadn't seen the community map until last night. So maybe people would add to it if they had seen it (not sure what else we could do to publicise it though - it's already Featured.)

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I hadn't seen the meta post at all. And as I'm a fairly heavy user of SE I should have. I would imagine lighter users may not see it at all.

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if we specifically are more mobile app based than other sites. On desktop the sidebar madness meta posts more obvious...