# Have we visited all the countries / territories as a community?

Tags: discussion, community

It occurred to me that while we have badges for tag experts etc, it might be useful to try and identify who has been to which countries/territories, as you could then ask that person about it in [chat].

If you're interested, I'm going to add an answer below and turn it into a Wiki answer. Please edit it to add your name if you live in or have spent time in any of these countries/regions.

Comment: Related: *[Where can one meet other Travel.SE members?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/)*, aka "Where we all live"

Comment: How do you define "spent time in"?  I can reel off 60+ countries that I have spent at least a couple of weeks in, but don't think a couple of weeks qualifies me as an expert on each of those countries.  So how do you qualify your expertise ... XX days in country, YY different times going to the country, ZZ years?

Comment: Perhaps an easier way would be some sort of JavaScript that searches for a country/place name in the profiles of all the members.

Comment: @WGroleau I don't think that's a good idea. This should be a voluntary list, IMO. Some people are purposefully omitting their names from certain (or all) countries, because they don't feel qualified (or don't want) to be pinged in [chat] with queries regarding said territory.

Comment: Right.  But they don't have to list any countries on their profile.

Comment: I can think of a more powerful list: people living where (and I see people already using the list for that).

Comment: @JanDoggen - http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/where-can-one-meet-other-travel-se-members

Comment: @WGroleau Having countries on their profile and here is a bit different. OP here specifically *mentions* the possibility of pinging people in [chat] asking for help. Also, it's more likely to be seen here.

Comment: @Fiksdal well it's just a possibility.  You're looking for someone that hopefully went where you want to go.  I've been to the US, for example, but never to Yellowstone Park, or the state of Georgia, or Michigan.  But the more we have recorded as having been there, the more likely to find someone we can know to ping. Hopefully. It's an experiment :)

Comment: MarkMayo: Yes, I think this list is a great idea. What I was discussing was the idea of @WGroleau to have a script automatically fetch countries off user profiles and add them to the list. I was discouraging the latter.

Comment: No, I was suggesting one which would just check the profiles for a specific place on request.  If I don't want anyone to know I went to Iceland, I wouldn't put it here OR in my profile.

Comment: @WGroleau Alright, but for reasons already stated I think it's better if everyone adds their names manually. There are already several people who have opted not to add their names for certain countries.

Comment: Well, with this much disagreement on "what is a country" I think back to my suggestion to put on your profile what you want others to know.  Alternatively, I move that the list be the 249 currently in use ISO 3166 two-letter codes.  And if someone is desperate for a sub-region, put it in parentheses after your name.

Comment: OK, I'm happy to add my name although I do not claim to be an expert on the 65+ countries I have visited, some for long periods, some fleetingly. I am new to Stack Exchange. How do I edit to add my name to the lists? Is there a way to batch enter all of them at once?

Comment: @AlanShanley manually, sorry ;)

Comment: What about landing there, but not staying; driving directly into another country?  What about driving through a country in a single day, stopping only for a meal and/or fuel?  What about passing through on a bus, with a meal stop?

Answer (score 44):

This list of countries is adapted from [ISO 3166](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search).

- Abkhazia - see Georgia
- Afghanistan - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Åland Islands - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Albania - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Algeria - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Galaxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27828/galaxy)
- Andorra - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Angola -
  - Cabinda -
- Anguilla - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)
- Antarctica - [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton)
- Antigua and Barbuda - [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Argentina - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas),  [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Armenia - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Artsakh - see Azerbaijan
- Aruba - [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Australia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Tim Malone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tim-malone), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza)
- Austria - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Austin W.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44305/omamarmy), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Azerbaijan - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [user568458](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3145/user568458), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [gdrt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/37602/gdrt)
- Artsakh - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb)
- The Bahamas - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Owen Versteeg](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43516/owen-versteeg), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Bahrain - [NVZ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39338/nvz), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal)
- Bangladesh - [kmonsoor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3809/kmonsoor), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal)
- Barbados - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [BLT](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52062/blt)
- Belarus - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Belgium - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Belize - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan)
- Benin - [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Bermuda - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Bhutan - [Ankur Banerjee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee), [kmonsoor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3809/kmonsoor)
- Bolivia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba -
- Bosnia and Herzegovina - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), ([hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail)), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Botswana - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [LShaver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/97150/lshaver)
- Bougainville
- Brazil - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- British Antarctic Territory - see Antarctica
- British Indian Ocean Territory -
- British Virgin Islands - [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Brunei - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza)
- Bulgaria - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Burkina Faso -
- Burma - see Myanmar
- Burundi -
- Cabo Verde - [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb)
- Cambodia - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Cameroon - [ptityeti](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13052/ptityeti), [Galaxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27828/galaxy)
- Canada - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Joe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19006/joe), [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Dipen Shah](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/29840/dipen-shah), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [LShaver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/97150/lshaver), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Cayman Islands - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [Joe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19006/joe), [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan)
- Central African Republic (CAR) -
- Chad -
- Chile - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)
- Easter Island - [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [Kuba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41551/kuba)
- China (PRC) - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland),[Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Tibet Autonomous Region - [ptityeti](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13052/ptityeti)
- ```
  also see Hong Kong, Macao, Taiwan
  ```
- Colombia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [LShaver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/97150/lshaver)
- Comoros -
- Congo, Democratic Republic of -  [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas)
- Congo, Republic of -
- Cook Islands -  [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Costa Rica - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail)
- Côte d'Ivoire -  [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Crimea - see Ukraine
  [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Croatia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Cuba - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot (GITMO)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Curaçao - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Cyprus - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Czech Republic - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Denmark - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Djibouti -
- Dominica - [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Dominican Republic - [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal)
- Ecuador - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Egypt - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- El Salvador -  [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [LShaver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/97150/lshaver), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau)
- Equatorial Guinea -
- Eritrea - [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Estonia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Ethiopia - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Falkland Islands - [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)
- Faroe Islands -  [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Fiji - [Berwyn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43570/berwyn), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo)
- Finland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- France - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Joel Damien](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41868/joel-damien), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [Galaxy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27828/galaxy), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [walen](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47549/walen), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- French Guiana - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Kuba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41551/kuba)
- French Polynesia - [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- French Southern Territories (Kerguelen, St. Paul & Amsterdam, Crozet, the Scattered Islands) -
- Adélie Land - see Antarctica
- Gabon -
- The Gambia - [user568458](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3145/user568458), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Georgia - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [JanDoggen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40521/jan-doggen), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Abkhazia -
- South Ossetia -
- Germany - [ThorstenS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7442/thorsten-s), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Joe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19006/joe), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [OmamArmy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44305/omamarmy), [Müller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46639/m%C3%BCller), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [Aganju](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5698738/aganju), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Tobias F.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74048/tobias-f), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Ghana - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Gibraltar - [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Greece - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46324/%CE%88%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%BA-%CE%9A%CF%89%CE%BD%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Greenland - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow)
- Grenada - [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43852/ryan-weaver)
- Guadeloupe - [Antzi](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24283/antzi), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Guam - [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw)
- Guatemala -  [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Guernsey - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Guinea -
- Guinea-Bissau -
- Guyana - [Kuba](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41551/kuba)
- Haiti - [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan)
- The Holy See - see Vatican City
- Honduras - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [LShaver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/97150/lshaver), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau)
- Hong Kong - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)
- Hungary - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila)
- Iceland - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Tim Malone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tim-malone), [Austin W.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44305/omamarmy), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- India - [NVZ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39338/nvz), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Ankur Banerjee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [kmonsoor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3809/kmonsoor), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Müller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46639/m%C3%BCller), [Dipen Shah](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/29840/dipen-shah), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Arulkumar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/55520/arulkumar), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [LShaver](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/97150/lshaver), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Indonesia - [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza)
- Iran - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Owen Versteeg](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43516/owen-versteeg), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Azerafati](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/33240/azerafati)
- Eastern Kurdistan -
- Iraq - [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid)
- Southern Kurdistan - [Müller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46639/m%C3%BCller), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Ireland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Isle of Man - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Israel - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Italy - [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Austin W.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44305/omamarmy), [Müller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46639/m%C3%BCller), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Tobias F.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74048/tobias-f), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Jamaica - [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Japan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Jersey - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Jordan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Kazakhstan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Kenya - [Andrew Ferrier](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2555/andrew-ferrier), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Kiribati -
- Korea, North (DPRK)- [Antzi](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/24283/antzi), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast),[schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Korea, South (ROK) - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [kmonsoor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3809/kmonsoor), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [revi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47344/revi), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Kosovo - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Kurdistan - see Iraq, Iran, Turkey, Syria
- Kuwait - [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Kyrgyzstan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow)
- Laos - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Latvia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Lebanon - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [AbAppletic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889375/abappletic), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince)
- Lesotho - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Liberia -
- Libya - [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Liechtenstein - [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow)
- Lithuania - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Luxembourg - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Macao - [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- North Macedonia - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ouflak](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/42478/ouflak)
- Madagascar - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Malawi - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Malaysia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Maldives - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Mali - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow)
- Malta - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Marshall Islands -
- Martinique - [Berwyn](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43570/berwyn), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Mauritania - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow)
- Mauritius - [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Mayotte - [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Mexico - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan), [Austin W.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44305/omamarmy), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [JanDoggen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40521/jan-doggen), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Micronesia (Federated States) -
- Moldova - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Transnistria - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Monaco - [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)
- Mongolia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Montenegro - [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza)
- Montserrat - [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc)
- Morocco - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Western Sahara -
- Mozambique - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Myanmar - [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)

### **The list continues in the below answer.**

*Please note - **please don't count airport stopovers as having been there**, and only countries / territories that **currently** have a claim to existing.  We're a travel site, not a history site :)

Comment: Cool, now we can check to which country to travel next to become the sole expert in this country

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55573/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-mayo-have-we-visited-all-the-countries-territorie) to facilitate further discussion, as it got a bit unwieldy with 80 comments.

Comment: One little thing: Guadeloupe and Martinique listed in this answer are not countries, they are insular regions from France. We may put them under France, don't we?
Same for Mayotte, Reunion, Saint Pierre and Miquelon...

Answer (score 33):

- Namibia - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [ThorstenS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7442/thorsten-s), [brhans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30555/brhans)
- Nauru -
- Nepal - [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Insanity](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46936/insanity), [JanDoggen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40521/jan-doggen), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Netherlands - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JanDoggen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40521/jan-doggen), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- New Caledonia - [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- New Zealand - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Tim Malone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tim-malone), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza)
- Nicaragua - [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Niger -
- Nigeria - [Aaron](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/826/aaron), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Niue -
- Northern Mariana Islands - [BESW](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/4398/besw), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland)
- Norway - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [ThorstenS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7442/thorsten-s), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Svalbard - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil)
- Oman - [NVZ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39338/nvz), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal)
- Pakistan - [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal)
- Palau -
- Palestinian Territories - [jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1893/jpatokal), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Panama - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [AbAppletic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889375/abappletic), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Papua New Guinea - [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Paraguay - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Peru - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [JanDoggen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40521/jan-doggen)
- The Philippines - [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [reirab](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12011/reirab), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [jcm](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46201/jcm), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau)
- Pitcairn Islands -
- Poland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Skipper](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/78472/skipper), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Tobias F.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74048/tobias-f), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus)
- Portugal - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Azores - [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot)
- Madeira - [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb)
- Qatar -  [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart) , [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey)
- Réunion - [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Romania - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [dandv](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11287/dan-dascalescu), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [walen](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47549/walen), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Russia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Crimea - see Ukraine
- Kaliningrad - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius)
- Rwanda - [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog)
- Saint Barthélemy - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster)
- Saint Helena, Ascension Island and Tristan da Cunha - [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)
- Saint Kitts and Nevis - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Saint Lucia - [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Saint Martin (French) - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Saint Martin (Dutch) - see Sint Maarten
- Saint Pierre and Miquelon -
- Saint Vincent and the Grenadines -
- Samoa - [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory)
- San Marino - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- São Tomé and Príncipe -
- Saudi Arabia - [NVZ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39338/nvz), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza)
- Senegal - [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop)
- Serbia - [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow)
- Kosovo - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Seychelles - [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Sierra Leone - [user568458](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3145/user568458), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Singapore - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Tim Malone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tim-malone), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Sinstein](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40391/sinstein), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Sint Eustatius - see Bonaire
- Sint Maarten - [choster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1480/choster), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Slovakia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila)
- Slovenia - [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Solomon Islands - [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Somalia -
- Somaliland -
- South Africa - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Insanity](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46936/insanity), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [brhans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30555/brhans)
- South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands - [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) [Martin Bonner](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52986/martin-bonner)
- South Ossetia - see Georgia
- South Sudan -
- Spain - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [gsamaras](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41906/gsamaras), [walen](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47549/walen), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Canary Islands - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Austin W.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/44305/austin-w), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [walen](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47549/walen), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Ceuta/Melilla - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Sri Lanka - [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Joel Damien](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41868/joel-damien), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Insanity](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/46936/insanity), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Sudan -
- Suriname -  [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Kuba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41551/kuba)
- Swaziland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Sweden - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Switzerland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [gsamaras](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41906/gsamaras), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Syria - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Western Kurdistan -
- Taiwan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Sinstein](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40391/sinstein)
- Tajikistan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo)
- Tanzania - [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Thailand - [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Tim Malone](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10264/tim-malone), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3145/user568458), [walen](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47549/walen), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Tibet - see China
- Timor-Leste -
- Togo - [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r)
- Tokelau -
- Tonga - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [user568458](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3145/user568458)
- Transnistria - see Moldova
- Trinidad and Tobago - [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Tunisia - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [user568458](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3145/user568458), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [gsamaras](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41906/gsamaras)
- Turkey - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Ankur Banerjee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [gsamaras](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41906/gsamaras), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Northern Kurdistan -
- Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus - see Cyprus
- Turkmenistan - [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Turks and Caicos Islands - [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Tuvalu -
- Uganda - [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- Ukraine - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Suncatcher](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42757/suncatcher), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Owen Versteeg](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/43516/owen-versteeg), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- Crimea - [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart)
- United Arab Emirates - [NVZ](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/39338/nvz), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Mikey](http://stackexchange.com/users/5393507/mikey), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal)
- United Kingdom -
- England - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Ankur Banerjee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/108/ankur-banerjee), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Joe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19006/joe), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Joel Damien](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41868/joel-damien), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [gsamaras](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41906/gsamaras), [walen](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47549/walen), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro), [brhans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30555/brhans)
- Northern Ireland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit)
- Scotland - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Joe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19006/joe), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Wales - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), ([hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail)), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [sztupy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8570/sztupy), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/52915/mast), [Wales](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [ahmedus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/63373/ahmedus), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane), [brhans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30555/brhans)
- United States of America - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog), [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal), [Jan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Karlson](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1372/karlson), [reirab](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12011/reirab), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [Greg Hewgill](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2363/greg-hewgill), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo), [mindcorrosive](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/793/mindcorrosive), [AbAppletic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5889375/abappletic), [Burhan Khalid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1375/burhan-khalid), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [fedorqui](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6997/fedorqui), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Joe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19006/joe), [Ryan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4453/ryan), [Matas Vaitkevicius](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32480/matas-vaitkevicius), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Kidburla](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4046/kidburla), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [dandv](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11287/dan-dascalescu), [Dipen Shah](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/29840/dipen-shah), [schmu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1014/byron-schmuland), [Mikey](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28676/mikey), [gigabytes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/59820/gigabytes), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [Aganju](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5698738/aganju), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Sean](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74643/sean), [UcieBila](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/90956/uciebila), [gsamaras](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/41906/gsamaras), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Weather Vane](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62763/weather-vane)
- U.S. outlying islands (Baker, Howland, Jarvis, Johnston, Kingman, Midway, Navassa, Palmyra, Wake) -
- American Samoa -
- Puerto Rico - [Robert Columbia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/47855/robert-columbia), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- United States Virgin Islands - [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai)
- Uruguay - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa)
- Uzbekistan - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash)
- Vanuatu -[Kate Gregory](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/46/kate-gregory), [Midavalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/40422/midavalo)
- Vatican City - [Fiksdal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41775/fiksdal),  [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [WGroleau](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [Aleks G](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14128/aleks-g), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [DavidB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19694/davidb), [Davinder](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/38009/davinder), [motoDrizzt](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27919/motodrizzt), [Mopelia](http://stackexchange.com/users/9273067/mopmop), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal), [Dirty-flow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2560/dirty-flow), [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau), [JakeDot](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/95392/JakeDot), [Tobias F.](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/74048/tobias-f), [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil), [Jumping Jezza](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75224/jumpingjezza), [Gerrit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2509/gerrit), [Zeocrash](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Venezuela - [Gayot](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow), [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc)
- Vietnam - [drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/8363/drat), [CMaster](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/26433/cmaster), [hippietrail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/140/hippietrail), [Zach](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), [George Y](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/47731/george-y), [Roddy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3161/roddy-of-the-frozen-peas), [EdC](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/36379/edc), [ivan](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1425/ivan), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince), [Itai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4801/itai), [Ayesh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11736/ayesh-k), [Nicolas R](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11614/nicolas-r), [Zeocrash](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/121/zeocrash), [MattAllegro](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77011/mattallegro)
- Wallis and Futuna -
- Western Sahara - see Morocco
- Yemen - [Mikey](http://stackexchange.com/users/5393507/mikey)
- Zambia - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [ThorstenS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7442/thorsten-s)
- Zimbabwe - [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo), [MastaBaba](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2271/mastababa), [Stuart](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/449/stuart), [ThorstenS](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/7442/thorsten-s)

---

*Please note - **please don't count airport stopovers as having been there**, and only countries / territories that **currently** have a claim to existing.  We're a travel site, not a history site :)

Comment: @pnuts Thus, the easiest way to complete this question is to persuade Charles Veley to join TSE.

Comment: @pnuts - All of it was in 2010 and separately in 2014. Sana'a and Hudaydah (and outlying areas) in 2010, Socotra and islands in 2014.  Return to Sana'a later in 2014.  All for tourism.

Comment: @pnuts - Yeah you need to go from Sharjah on Felix Airlines.  I was living in Abu Dhabi so we just drove to Sharjah Emirate and got a flight.  At the time it was Sharjah-Mukala-Socotra.  I don't know how to start a 'chat,' but I can tell you details about the logistics if you like. [Sorry my first response I thought you'd asked 'where'.]

Comment: Hm, I *might* tick off *Palau* and *American Samoa* if I felt a one-day visit  justified sufficient qualification (then again, those are comparatively small islands)

Comment: -1 for Crimea as a sub-item of Russia. Otherwise, we would have to list all zones of temporary occupation here. Like ISIS-controlled territories of Iraq and Syria.

Comment: @bytebuster This list of countries is adapted from ISO 3166.

Comment: @Revetahw, it would make sense if ISO 3166 contained Crimea.

Comment: @bytebuster Meh, I don't know, I didn't make this list. Just copied it because it was too long for one answer.

Comment: Curious whether there's a reason for Guam being in the 'G' list but other territories being shown subordinate to USA.

Comment: Add me to Turkmenistan if it helps

Answer (score 28):

Five months on, these places on our list have had 'no visitors' (if [the map](https://www.amcharts.com/visited_countries/#AX,AL,AM,AT,AZ,BY,BE,BA,BG,HR,CY,CZ,DK,EE,FO,FI,FR,GE,DE,GI,GR,GG,HU,IS,IE,IM,IT,JE,XK,LV,LI,LT,LU,MK,MT,MD,MC,ME,NL,NO,PL,PT,RO,RU,SM,RS,SK,SI,ES,SJ,SE,CH,TR,UA,GB,VA,AI,AG,AW,BS,BB,BZ,BM,VG,CA,KY,CR,CU,CW,DM,DO,SV,GL,GP,GT,HT,HN,JM,MQ,MX,MS,NI,PA,PR,BL,KN,LC,MF,SX,TC,US,VI,AR,BO,BR,CL,CO,EC,FK,GF,GY,PY,PE,GS,SR,UY,VE,DZ,AO,BW,CV,CI,CD,EG,SZ,ET,GA,GM,GH,KE,LS,MG,MW,ML,MR,MA,MZ,NA,CG,RW,SN,SL,SO,ZA,SD,TZ,TG,TN,UG,ZM,ZW,AF,BH,BD,BT,BN,KH,CN,HK,IN,ID,IR,IQ,IL,JP,JO,KZ,KW,KG,LA,LB,MO,MY,MN,MM,NP,KP,OM,PK,PS,PH,QA,SA,SG,KR,LK,SY,TW,TJ,TH,TM,AE,UZ,VN,YE,AU,CK,FJ,PF,NC,NZ,PG,WS,SB,TO,TV,VU) is up-to-date!):

[image]

- Africa - Benin, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cameroon, CAR, Chad, Comoros, Djibouti, Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea, Guinea, Guinea-Bissau, Liberia, Libya, Mauritius, Mayotte, Niger, Nigeria, Reunion, São Tomé and Príncipe, Somalia, South Sudan, Western Sahara.
- Asia - British Indian Ocean Territory, Timor-Leste.
- Atlantic Islands - French Southern Territories, Tristan Da Cunha, Saint Helena
- Pacific islands - American Samoa, Kiribati, Marshall Islands, Micronesia, Nauru, Niue, Palau, Pitcairn Islands, Tokelau, Tuvalu, Wallis and Futuna.
- North America - Bonaire/Sint Eustatius/Saba, Grenada, Saint Pierre and Miquelon, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines.

Country-level visitation is quite a low standard, but even by this crude measure, we have an enormous gap across central Africa. Imagine if we took this down to the [county level](http://www.mob-rule.com/user-gifs/choster.gif); I don't even crack the 16% mark for the U.S.

Standouts to me include Nigeria, the largest economy and most populous country in Africa; and Trinidad and Tobago, a major transportation and commercial hub.

Minor surprises: Burundi, recently popular among backpackers as an add-on to Rwanda; and world-traveler-bucket-list topper Tristan da Cunha.

Comment: ...as all the places I have already been have already someone else name on them, this post is making me consider to take my motorbike, start from Libia, and put my flag on all the african's grey nations on that map...

Comment: Svalbard (Spitsbergen), the red blob above Norway, has also been visited by me.

Comment: @pnuts Not when it's over 30k chars...

Comment: I had plans to visit Dili (Timor-Leste) last month but had to change plans. 2017 Feb perhaps :)

Comment: What a great answer. Using an image to depict the question shows an interesting factoid as well as summarising the countries. Very nice indeed.

Comment: You can tick off Svalbard.

Comment: @jpatokal You've been to Svalbard, but not Norway?

Comment: @Fiksdal I only filled in interesting countries...

Comment: You can cross Turkmenistan off that list, I'm now TSE's resident Turkmenistan guy :P

Comment: @zeocrash This is a community wiki; you can remove it yourself. And welcome. :).

Comment: brb, just firing up mspaint :P

Comment: I'm actually a Nigerian prince, please add me to this list.

Comment: Have added Trinidad and Tobago to the list - the first reader. A full week in each island.

Comment: Nigeria done by 2 users!!

Answer (score 3):

Unvisited list so far (please edit):

- Abkhazia
- American Samoa
- Benin
- Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba
- British Indian Ocean Territory
- Burkina Faso
- Burundi
- Chad
- Comoros
- Djibouti
- Equatorial Guinea
- Guinea
- Guinea-Bissau
- Kiribati
- Liberia
- Marshall Islands
- Mayotte
- Micronesia (Federated States)
- Nauru
- Niger
- Nigeria
- Niue
- Palau
- Pitcairn Islands
- Saint Pierre and Miquelon
- Saint Vincent and the Grenadines
- São Tomé and Príncipe
- Somalia
- Somaliland
- South Ossetia
- South Sudan
- Timor-Leste
- Tokelau
- Tuvalu
- U.S. outlying islands (Baker, Howland, Jarvis, Johnston, Kingman, Midway, Navassa, Palmyra, Wake)
- Wallis and Futuna
- Western Sahara

Comment: I've visited Tibet, but per the other list it's considered a part of China.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised no one has listed American Samoa, the Federated States of Micronesia or the Marshall Islands. I guess I need to go book the [Island Hopper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_Hopper) now.

Comment: @Berwyn Nigeria done ;)