# What's with the red 'stripe' in Africa?

Tags: discussion

I refer to the world map posted [here](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3999/1737).

There is an unbroken red stripe in central Africa starting at the Med and extending down to about Cameroon. Nobody has been there and that may reveal a factoid of some sort.  I know that the 'crescent' formed by the countries between Ghana and Cameroon (inclusive) have wretched internet services and wonder if this might be an influence. Consider some explanations...

- We have had nationals of those countries (especially Ghana and
  Nigeria) show up with visa refusals. But for some reason they are not
  interested in participating in the survey; OR
- Travellers to those countries are road warriors so rugged and
  weathered that they don't find TSE a useful thing; OR
- Those places are not as interesting as other places (but lots of road warriors travel for width, not depth, so this alternative is disputable); OR
- Some other reason, tell me what it is.

What's a good reason for that distinctive red stripe in central Africa? If it reveals some way to make TSE better or to broaden our user base, then let's find out and put it to work.

Comment: 'Dangerous' countries? Hard to access visa wise?

Comment: I noticed that Africa was surprisingly unrepresented. Many of the countries that are visited also had a small number of visitors, including some surprising ones like Gambia. My guess is that, this site has a disproportionate number of "tech" related people, and much of Africa (with a few exceptions like SA, Rwanda, Ethiopia, Nigeria) doesn't have much in the way of tech industries (though, curiously, Nigeria is one of the un-visited?)

Comment: Also, consider the flip-side of the question: why are off-the-beaten-track destinations for 1st-world English-speakers in Asia, South America and Oceana so comprehensively represented? I'd guess: because geeks love Asia, because Americans can explore South America relatively easily, and, for Oceania, erm... because Stack Overflow users love boats? (or maybe, because it's on Mark Mayo's doorstep?)

Comment: If the rest of the world was colour coded by how many users have mentioned being there, it might be easier to investigate. Also, a map of the world coloured by how many questions have been tagged with that country would be cool.

Answer (score 8):

I was in the southern region of Africa and this are my reasons to not even consider it as travel destination:

- Extremely poor: Niger, Chad, Central African Republic and Congo are at the last places of the [Human Development Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index). We are talking about poor of "poor": having not enough water and food, parents not being able to feed their children, no medicine. no infrastructure, nothing. Only excess of misery.
- War and terror: After Gaddafis removal Libya has ongoing civil war. All other countries are known as dictatorships/ failed "democracies" with extremely lousy human right record and long periods of civil war and instability. Most of the countries are also known to have employed children as soldiers. Boko Haram has strongholds in Niger and Chad and al-Quaeda has strongholds in the whole region of North Africa. Many medical personnel and tourists have been kidnapped and killed. The red stripe at the western coast is Liberia & Co., well-known by sailors for extreme pirate activity.
- No travel opportunity: No infrastructure, "streets", if they exist, are extremely lousy and often mined. The only safe places are very small, sealed-off tourist places.
- Severe diseases and epidemic: malaria, dengue fever, bilharzia, rift valley fever, cholera, meningitis. The Central African Republic has also (still!) leprosy and sleeping sickness. The hygienic conditions are abominal and if you get sick, you can only hope that you are near enough to an airport to get flown out. Children are still infected with polio which has been eradicated from almost all other countries.

Comment: @pnuts In those countries such people will belong to a very small minority meaning that they will be away from the slums and/or behind guarded fortresses. The other thing is if you experience poorness itself (During our 2001 tour to the sun eclipse we needed to get gas from the black market; Simbabwe had gas supply problems). If you have a heart left, you will feel guilt, especially because people are still friendly despite being poor. I do not know how I could explain to residents what exactly I am doing in such countries...misery viewing ? Why do I not give everything I have if I am there ?