# Geographical distribution of Travel Stack Exchange users?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this is an appropriate question for this site, but I just wonder where the users of this site, Travel StackExchange, are located.

Is there an official/unofficial statistics or user survey about this?

Answer (score 2):

Folks can pop their location in their profile, but not many do. There is no accurate way to find out where they are without that, as they could use VPNs or other mechanisms, so I think you're out of luck if you want a comprehensive survey.

Additionally, there is a [post on which countries people have been to](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3907/1381).